# Android library fails to initialize in sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Method

```
PayPal.initWithAppID(this, appID, server);
```

fails in sandbox. Same code was working fine yesterday.

Comment: Same thing happens also with PayPal.ENV_NONE

Comment: Have you changed anything since it was working? Good place to start... Of course if you are connecting to paypal check to see if that is connecting

Comment: I didn't change anything, the same app simply stopped working.

Comment: Q: Is there a way to enable logging in library to see requests/responses and error messages?

Comment: Try something like this: https://apigee.com/console/paypal

Comment: That is great, but can you tell me which services are invoked by PayPal.initWithAppID?

Comment: The problem miraculously disappeared just now.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Sandbox initialization fails everytime i execute the app but i wonts fine in evn.none. Please advise